# Can I use the same junction box for two appliances?

Tags: wiring, grounding, appliances, junction-box

Complete noob here.

I'm finishing building my kitchen and the last part - the wiring of electrical oven and glass cooking plates, is presenting me with some challenges.

I am located in Germany.

The oven comes out with a 3 pronged cable (I guess active, neutral and ground?).

[image: oven cables]

The cookers were sold to me with no cable.

There is *one* junction box at the intended spot in the kitchen, with 5 cable grips, which is definitely 3 phase.

[image: junction box]

I'm wondering what's the best course of action with both the oven and the cooking plates.

My thoughts so far:

- Is there a way to connect the cooking plates to the same junction box as the oven somehow, without blowing things up?
- If not, should I just connect them to a nearby socket with a cable ending with a regular socket plug?
- What about the oven (single phase cables) vs the junction box (3 phase)?

Note: the sockets seem to have ground clips here - see picture below.

[image: socket]

Comment: Before rushing in and connecting color to color, it would be a very good idea to use a multimeter and check as I think there are 5 wires which is possibly 3-phase. And the Swiss do the same thing...

Comment: @SolarMike you were right (I checked the fuses without even bothering with the mm). Well, that complicates things even further I guess...

Comment: Need to see the hob too. I would guess that the hob uses two phases 16A and the oven 1 phase 16A.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere thanks for helping out. At a first glance, the hob seemed to support both 3 phase and single phase, but it was sold to me with no cable. I can post a picture later today if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a mm and check the voltage between the wires (phases).

Ignore the green/yellow for this.

If the black is neutral (likely) then the voltage between any of the other 3 and the neutral should be around 380V.

Between any 2 phases (brown, gray, blue) should give you 230V.

So, as the load on phases should be balanced, I suggest you get a competent electrician to check and connect this for you. That way (s)he can check which appliances are on which phase.

I had an issue with my hob.. puled the oven out to clean it and a wire popped out for the hob. Not thinking I put it back (blue to blue)... Massive bang and off to buy another hob :) happy days... Made sure of the voltages before connecting the new one...

Comment: Sigh... I guess I'll have to get someone to do this for me as you say :( Do you think it's technicaly feasible to have both appliances on the same junction box?

Comment: I have a 3-phase oven and a single phase cooker on the same point works fine, this may depend on the regulations in your area, so a good electrician will have this done in an hour... Much less cost than the grief...

Comment: definitely will be looking for some qualified help - hopefully I can even learn a thing or two in the process :) Thanks again

Comment: Blue is likely to be the neutral in Europe; Brown/Black/Grey are standard phase colours. Black neutral is old UK & colonies.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere phase colors are red, yellow & blue for some, so be careful... making such sweeping statements can cause lots of problems : just use a meter...

Comment: @Solar Mike My statement is no more sweeping than yours - we both said likely. And I don't believe RYB has ever been used in Germany, whereas what is seen in the image is new equipment (lists 400V not 380V) with EU standard colour codes.

Comment: So with a hob how do you  hook up the two loads ? One cord /Two and a splice? Other than talking about voltage no real answer .